# How to store build artifacts in Artifacts feed?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build pipeline that publishes a release artifact for consumption by the release pipeline.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - npm
  - msbuild

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'npm Cache'
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ABCDashboard/Angular/package-lock.json'
    path: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ABCDashboard/Angular/node_modules'
    cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'
    restoreKeys: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)"'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm ci'
  inputs:
    command: ci
    workingDir: ABCDashboard/Angular
    verbose: false
  condition: eq(variables['CACHE_RESTORED'],False)

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom: angular build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: ABCDashboard/Angular
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run-script build -- --prod'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: '.Net build | Build solution (No need to build test as well)'
  inputs:
    solution: 'ABCDashboard/*.csproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: Release
    msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    clean: true

- task: Snyk.snyk-security-scan.custom-build-release-task.SnykSecurityScan@0
  displayName: 'Snyk scan for open source vulnerabilities'
  inputs:
    serviceConnectionEndpoint: SnykAuthFreeTier
    failOnIssues: false
    testDirectory: ABCDashboard
    additionalArguments: '-d --all-projects'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/ABCDashboard'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: ABCDashboard
    Contents: |
     Bundles/**
     !(packages.config|phantomjs-license.txt)
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/ABCDashboard'

- script: |
   cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/ABCDashboard
   
   ls -ltr
   
  displayName: 'List artifacts under $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/ABCDashboard'
  enabled: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/ABCDashboard'
    Contents: |
     assets/**
     bin/**
     Bundles/**
     Content/**
     Scripts/**
     Views/**
     Web.config
     Web.Dev.config
     Web.Test.config
     Web.Prod.config
     Web.Beta.config
     Web.Sandbox.config
     ApplicationInsights.config
     *.asax
     *.ico
     *.txt
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    verbose: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Release'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
    ArtifactName: Release
```

[image: release]

I am looking into Azure Devops Artifacts, and from what I understand, we can create feeds to store those published build artifacts?

From my understanding, those kind of build artifacts my pipeline publishes are considered "Universal Packages"? and If so, I would have to add a Universal Package task like so in order for the build artifact (e.g. Release) to be stored in the Artifacts feed?

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    vstsFeedPublish: 'feedname'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: test
    versionOption: custom
    versionPublish: 1.1.0
```

I had already gone ahead and created a feed, do I just wait for next time I run a pipeline for a Release artifact to show up in the feed? or do I have to add "upstream sources" first? If upstream sources is a required step, I selected "Azure Artifacts feed in this organization" as the upstream source type and then when going over the configuration setting, for some reason, it's complaining that "This feed has no available views to be used as an upstream source" despite defined views as shown here:

[image: view]

[image: view greyed out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you can use feed to store Build artifacts.

> From my understanding, those kind of build artifacts my pipeline publishes are considered "Universal Packages"?

Your understanding is correct. You can use Universal Package Publish task to upload the build artifacts to Azure Feed.

> Do i just wait for next time I run a pipeline for a Release artifact to show up in the feed? or do i have to add "upstream sources" first?

You don't need to add upstream sources for the feed.

To publish the Universal Package, you can directly use Universal Package Publish task in Pipeline.

For example:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    vstsFeedPublish: 'name'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: kevintest
```

**Result:**

[image]

To use the published Universal Package, you can directly use Universal Package download task.

For example:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal download'
  inputs:
    command: download
    vstsFeed: 'name'
    vstsFeedPackage: 'name'
    vstsPackageVersion: 0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. So this is something I can just add after my last task (publishArtifacts)? Also, I'm somewhat lost on versioning. Is there a default option where i let it increment the numbers (major/minor/patch)?

Comment: Hi @Cataster. Yes, you can directly add the publish Universal Packages task after your last task. It can work. For the option to let it increment the numbers, you can define the field: **versionOption: minor or major or patch** in the task. Refer to this doc about the task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I read somewhere that the caching task can store the cache in the Artifacts. Currently when we add a new library to the packages.json, we dont know how to invalidate the cache and run a new one. so what happens is we have to disable the cache task in the build pipeline, remove the cache key `condition: eq(variables['CACHE_RESTORED'],False)` for npm to install again, then re-enable the cache task again. I asked this before on a microsoft forum but wasnt given a good answer: is there a way to delete the cache? maybe we can use this Artifacts to delete it?

Comment: I guess i could run something like this to remove the cache `rm -rf $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ABCDashboard/Angular/node_modules` but we wouldnt want to remove the cache everytime...what condition would i need to make sure it only removes the cache only when new dependencies are added? for example,  an addition to the private dependencies such as `"runtime-config-loader": "^3.0.0"`, requires installing a new npm package.